# ArrayList of ArrayLists - clear function confusion

Tags: java

Here is a particular method I have written:

```
class A {

    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inputTerms = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void method1(ArrayList<Integer> terms) {
        ArrayList<Integer> clauses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int N = terms.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                clauses.add(-terms.get(i));
                clauses.add(-terms.get(j));
                inputTerms.add(clauses);
                clauses.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called multiple times from the main function.
In the end, i try to write the contents of the class variable into a file. However, when I do this, i get 0 as the contents of inputTerms. However, if i remove the clauses.clear() line, i am able to get approppriate values.

My program is such that it is vital for me to clear the clauses after adding to inputTerms. Is there any alternative to this?

**Hmmm.. I have done what you've suggested. However, I haven't quite overcome the problem. To give more background, in my main function, I have the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++){ 
ArrayList<Integer> firstdiagonalTerms = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for (int j=0; j<N-i; j++){ 
firstdiagonalTerms.add(variable[j][i+j]); 
} 
method1(firstdiagonalTerms);
}
```

I have to call the method1 function 4 times for different combinations of 'i' and 'j'. However, I still get 0 when I use the above mentioned suggestions**

Comment: Do you mean you get the number 0, or inputTerms is empty?

Comment: i get inputTerms as empty, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the same list and clearing it repeatedly. When you add an object to a list it copies a reference to it, not a copy of the object.

```
int N = terms.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        List<Integer> clauses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        clauses.add(-terms.get(i));
        clauses.add(-terms.get(j));
        inputTerms.add(clauses);
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0, N = terms.size(); i < N - 1; i++) 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) 
        inputTerms.add(Arrays.asList(-terms.get(i), -terms.get(j)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call clear() on list, you are updating/removing same objects (because list contains reference to objects, not copy of object). That is what causing the issue.

I think you need to do something like below. Instead of using clear(), create a new list everytime.

```
public static void method1 (ArrayList<Integer> terms)
{

int N = terms.size();       
        for (int i = 0; i<N-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
              ArrayList<Integer> clauses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              clauses.add(-terms.get(i));
              clauses.add(-terms.get(j));
              inputTerms.add(clauses);

}
}
```

Comment: @downvoter: If no comment, its hard to know what is wrong with answer. I am happy to correct my answer, if you have valid point.

Comment: The purpose of the question was to get around the fact that when you clear the list, all values are removed from a separate list that the values where just added from. Your answer doesn't indicate why this happens, rather just a work around (although quite valid).

Comment: Hmmm.. I have done what you ve suggested. However, I havent quite overcome the problem. To give more background, in my main function, i have the following code:  for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++){
   ArrayList<Integer> firstdiagonalTerms = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for (int j=0; j<N-i; j++){
           firstdiagonalTerms.add(variable[j][i+j]);
   }
   
   method1(firstdiagonalTerms);
    }  i have to call the method1 fuction 4 times for different combinations of 'i' and 'j'. However, i still get 0 when i use the above mentioned suggestions

Comment: @user1646637: Please update question with updated code. Because of formatting I couldn't understand the code.

Comment: ZERO from where? inputTerms? I would suggest post a brand new question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand what you are trying to achieve, but you keep reusing the same list, which is probably not what you meant to do.

You should probably move the `ArrayList<Integer> clauses = new ArrayList<Integer>();` inside the inner loop, and not call `clauses.clear()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding "clauses" you are adding the actual object to the arrayList, not a copy. So when you clear them all the values in the list will be removed. To get arround this, add a clone of the list:

```
inputTerms.add((ArrayList<Integer>) clauses.clone());
```